# Thread safe two-way communucation between main thread and a single long-running thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an application that has a class/process that does some heavy lifting with a 3rd party C based native library. This library has some of its own dependencies and data that it loads into memory (close to 500MB) at first run. It takes several seconds to load, so it needs to happen only once. This controlling class also builds a large hashmap of objects that's pulled from a database that's used with the native library.

My problem is this. The controlling class needs to have the large hashmap updated and referenced externally. For example: when there's an update externally, the relevant object in the hashmap needs to have its contents updated and when the main thread needs to use a particular object within the hashmap, it needs access to it or a copy of it. I keep saying "main thread" but the reality is that the main portion of the application uses an event listener from another native library that is multithreaded. And new events come in fast (in the range of 100 to 200 per second, and will likely be higher in production).

What I need is a thread-safe way to pass data back and forth. My first thought was to use a singleton, and this worked with a low number of requests (15 per second), but as soon as that ramped up I was getting threading issues that crashed the JVM. My next thought was to use a blockingqueue, but as far as I can tell there's no way to reliably do two-way communication.

Let me explain that last statement (I know about dequeue). What has to happen is when a process says to the controlling class "I need object 74", it needs to be able to return object 74. With dequeue if two separate processes request an object (say 74 and the other asks for 89) then there's no way to guarantee that each process will get the right one. At least not until after the fact when it receives the object and checks which one it is.

I next considered an event listener pattern within the application itself. Basically the main logic class (the one sending the updates and requesting copies) would pass a reference of itself to the controller class and the controller class would implement the @Override methods. I'm not even sure if that's a good idea, but I didn't even get very far before I realized it wouldn't be thread-safe either.

So I'm stuck trying to think of design pattern that will work here. Normally I can push through these kinds of problems, but with a recent death in the family has left me staring at my screen with no solutions. I know this is an age old problem that's been solved a million times over, but I just can't work through the process right now.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That first paragraph is unclear as to what is happening *inside* the C library and what is happening inside the Java app. I suggest editing to clarify. Also, you should describe the technical means by which you communicate between C and Java.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What the C library does is not relevant. Everything I'm trying to solve is within Java itself. The Java portion is the business logic and needs to be thread safe. Communication with the C libraries works as intended. So there are no issues with that. In fact, mentioning the C libraries was unnecessary in describing my problem.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to have concurrent random access to an object by some index. So why does not `ConcurrentHashMap` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to St.Antario (in the comments above).

The first thing I tried was ConcurrentHashMap but I second guessed myself because of the non-thread safe nature of the 3rd party library.

Ultimately, the solution was to sequester the native library and run it in its own thread. I pass data to the native library via BlockingQueue. So elsewhere in my code I just use a myQueue.put(data) call to pass the data. And this is working well now.

Here's what the native library thread code looks like:

```
public void Start() {
    Runnable task = () -> {
        try {
            /* SETUP NATIVE LIBRARY */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (keepRunning) {
            while (!myQueue.isEmpty()) {
                Process_Run();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        myThread = new Thread(task); // Run the task in a background thread
        myThread.setDaemon(true); // Terminate the running thread if the application exits
        myThread.start(); // Start the thread
    }

private void Process_Run() {
    try {
        MyCustomData myData = myQueue.take();
        /*  DO STUFF  */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```